# How to append data to request form.submit()

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, forms

I am trying to submit a form using POST, but I have some additional data from `<p>` tags that I have stored into JS object.  I want to send that to server when I hit `form.submit()` from JavaScript.

```html
<p> the text i want to send </p>
<form action="url" id="invoice-form">
    <input type="text" name="input"> 
</form>


Edit:[Updated Title]
<a id="submit" type="button">Submit</a>

<script>
let data = $('p').text()

$('#invoice-form').submit()
```

What I am trying to do is to send `data` with `submit` event

Comment: What's with the "JSON" reference in the title?

Comment: I will be sending the data to server after converting the JS object to JSON using .stringify()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could attach an `onclick` handler to the button and use `fetch` to send the data in JSON format to the server.

```js
const onclick = (e) => {
  const data = {
    data: document.querySelector('input').value
  }


  e.preventDefault();

  fetch("/server-end-point", {
    method: 'POST',
    mode: 'no-cors',
    cache: 'no-cache',
    credentials: 'same-origin',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data) // body data type must match "Content-Type" header
  });
}

const button = document.querySelector('#submit');

button.onclick = onclick;
```

```html
<p> the text i want to send </p>
<form action="url" id="invoice-form">
    <input type="text" name="input"> 
    <button id="submit" type="button">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**More info about Fetch:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch
**Is fetch supported in your browser targets:** https://caniuse.com/fetch

Comment: I appreciate the response, but I wanted to do it synchronously that's why I didn't use this due the nature of its working.

Answer (score 0):

The JSON in the title does not seem to be relevant

1. Change the link to a submit button
2. Add a submit event handler that copies the data
3. Allow the submit to send to server

```js
$("#invoice-form").on("submit", function(e) {
  let data = $('p').text()
  $("#input").val(data)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p> the text i want to send </p>
<form action="url" id="invoice-form">
  <input type="text" name="input" id="input">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

If you want to Ajax the value, just change to this

```js
$("#invoice-form").on("submit", function(e) {
  e.prevenDefault();
  let data = $('p').text()
  $.post(this.action,{"input":data})
});
```

Comment: I feel silly to ask such a question which has so simple solution.

Comment: I wanted to it synchronously, your answer does it all. Thanks @mplungjan

Comment: @Andreas Updated with explanations

Comment: is there a way to pass the data into the QueryDICT ??

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=submit+text+to+querydict+site:stackoverflow.com